# Stream 4K movies on Mac mini?

Tags: 4k-resolution

I have this older Mac mini:

https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i5-2.5-late-2012-specs.html

And it seems to stream 4K movies/trailers from YouTube ok - not perfect but definitely watchable.

I currently have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it and played around with xrandr to configure it to 3840x2160 but even when it says it’s running that resolution it does not really look like it.

So next up is trying to reinstall latest OSX to see if I can select that resolution out of the box.

But after googling a bit on hardware requirement for 4K I seems that my Mac mini should not be able to stream it at all. So I am a bit confused are most articles about editing 4K movies? And should I expect that my Mac mini can stream 4K movies just fine?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the actual first 4k TV was invented/made in April 2013 a year after your Mac mini was made. The graphics card (controls how good your graphics are in terms of resolution/coloring) is the "Intel HD Graphics 4000" which through HDMI cables can only stream 1920x1080 (1080p) resolution. 4K resolution is 3840 x 2160 pixels. Even through another way called Display port, that can boost up the Intel Graphic 4000 card to 2560×1600. So it is impossible with the Mac mini to stream 4k. Unless you go inside it and add a new graphics card. Find out what the maximum resolution for some Apple TV's and pick one that can stream 4K. I don't believe you can edit movies or videos on an Apple TV. Unless iMovie is on Apple TV. ¯_(ツ)_/¯